# passing class member to method

Tags: java, jpa, querydsl

Hi I want to write a general sorting method

```
public mySortMethod(Customer customer, Customer.member sortBy) {
       return query.from(customer).orderBy(customer.sortBy.asc());
}
```

so I will be able to do call the method like this

```
mySortMethod(myCustomer,Customer.name)
```

is there a way to pass a class member to a method (and to verify that the parameters "is a type of" `MyClass.members` ) ?

I am using Java and QueryDSL JPA
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could maybe use reflection to do this (not very elegantly):

```
  public static <T> ArrayList<T> mySortMethod(T aClass, String sortBy){
      try {
        Field sortByField=aClass.getClass().getField(sortBy); // bombs out if field doesn't exist
        return something like query.from(aClass).orderby(sortByField.getName());
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        throw new BlahBlahException ("Field "+sortBy+" isn't a member of class "+aClass.getClass().getName(),e);
   } catch (SecurityException e) {
       throw new BlahBlahException ("Field "+sortBy+" in class "+aClass.getClass().getName()+" is not accessible",e);
    }
  }
```

you would call it in this not very elegant fashion:

```
mySortMethod(customer, "customerLastName");
```

where we assume you've made a `Customer` class that has a field called `customerLastName`, among others.

Note that this is a generic method, not restricted to class Customer. You can pass objects of any class in. For instance

```
mySortMethod(customerAddress, "city");
```

Answer (score 0):

why you don't use @orderby annotation in your entity class

**@OrderBy**

Dynamic ordering can be done with the @OrderBy annotation.
 “Dynamically” means that the ordering of the elements of a collection is made when the association is retrieved.

```
@Entity
public class Comment {
@Id @GeneratedValue
private Long id;
private String nickname;
private String content;
private Integer note;
@Column(name = "posted_date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date postedDate;
// Constructors, getters, setters
}
```

Listing 3-54. The Comments of a News Entity Are Ordered by Descending Posted Date

```
@Entity
public class News {
@Id @GeneratedValue
private Long id;
@Column(nullable = false)
private String content;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@OrderBy("postedDate DESC")
private List<Comment> comments;
// Constructors, getters, setters
}
```

The @OrderBy annotation takes as parameters the names of the attributes on which the sorting has to be made (the postedDate attribute), as well as the method (ascending or descending).

The string ASC  r DESC can be used for sorting in either an ascending or descending manner, respectively.

You can have several columns used in the @OrderBy annotation. If you need to order by posted date and note, you can use OrderBy("postedDate DESC, note ASC").

The @OrderBy annotation doesn’t have any impact on the database mapping. 
The persistence provider is simply informed to use an order by clause when the collection is  retrieved.

Comment: Thanks ,not sure that I understood. The user is actually sending what he wants to order by and the order direction (ASC/DSC) . how can it be done dynamically ? can you share an example please ?